# How to resolve JDK version mismatch between compiled class version and runtime version?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar, compilation

I am working on a MapReduce Java project in eclipse (on Ubuntu 14.04LTS) for which I am using Apache Avro serialization framework for that I need avro-tools-1.7.7.jar file. I have downloaded this jar from apache website and I have written the java code using the downloaded jar. When I execute the program I am getting java.lang.VerifyError error. I have read from few website that this error is due to a version mismatch between the JDK version of compiled class files in the jar to the runtime JDK version. So I checked the version of a class from my current project.

```
srimanth@srimanth-Inspiron-N5110:~$ javap -verbose CCHD\&CCHA/TimeForMapReduce/bin/practice/ArrayWritableX.class 
Classfile /home/srimanth/CCHD&CCHA/TimeForMapReduce/bin/practice/ArrayWritableX.class
  Last modified 19 Apr, 2015; size 1234 bytes
  MD5 checksum 9a3d03ca0f126bf7ee65d14099108984
  Compiled from "ArrayWritableX.java"
public class practice.ArrayWritableX
  SourceFile: "ArrayWritableX.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
```

it shows that the JDK version that I am using is 51. I extracted that class files from that jar and I checked that version of the class files. It shows that the version is 50.

```
srimanth@srimanth-Inspiron-N5110:~$ javap -verbose org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroCollector.class 
Classfile /home/srimanth/org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroCollector.class
  Last modified 18 Jul, 2014; size 603 bytes
  MD5 checksum d1a99c2d2ad48c8ed9d02d6b45708f70
  Compiled from "AvroCollector.java"
public abstract class org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroCollector<T extends java.lang.Object> extends org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured
  Signature: #19                          // <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configured;
  SourceFile: "AvroCollector.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
```

How do I resolve this. Is there any way to recompile entire class files in the jar file? or do I need to downgrade my JDK?

additional info: I am not using maven

Thanks in advance. I appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

For your custom classes and default JDK, you are using 1.7 while the hadoop classes are compiled using JDK1.6.

So change your JAVA_HOME variable so that it points to JDK 6 kit rather than JDK7. Post that recompile all your classes and rebuild the jar if any.

Comment: So I need to download openjdk-6-jdk and openjre-6-jre?

Comment: I suggest using Oracle java jdk instead of OpenJDK. Open jdk is not compatible with hadoop. you may phase some issues in future.